# Special unicode question mark characters in database table

Tags: sql, database, unicode, utf-8, special-characters

Firstly anyone who reads this and response, thanks for your assistance.

I'm having a problem where I have a site (primarily in English), with many translations for different language. I have a database which stores these translations. Unfortunately one of the language seems to be populated with question mark characters between each general character. Because of this, any text which contains these characters wont show up in IE.

Is there any SQL statements that will seek these characters out and remove them? There's a find/replace option, but I can't seem to find a rule that applies.

Thanks for any help you can give.

As an example, this is how text shows in a table:

�i�O�N� �k�i�t� �d�e� �s�u�p�p�o�r�t� �V�é�l�o� - which stops it showing IE.

Removing these as below will show it in IE:
iON kit de support Vélo

Any idea how I go about this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are your database fields `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: What dbms are you using? What's the column datatype?

Comment: select REGEXP_REPLACE('asdasd???asdasd??123','[?]','') from dual;
  for oracle,

Comment: Hey,

The column is formatted as "text" and collation as "utf8_general_ci"

The dbms is PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

Your translation database contains mangled data that has come from misinterpreting UTF-16-encoded input as ISO-8859-1 (or the closely related Windows code page 1252; you can't tell the difference from the example data).

You could attempt to undo the damage by extracting the data, encoding it back to what is hopefully the original set of bytes, and re-decoding it, then inserting it back into the database. For example in PHP:

```
$mangled = "i\0O\0N\0 \0k\0i\0t\0 \0d\0e\0 \0s\0u\0p\0p\0o\0r\0t\0 \0V\0\xE9\0l\0o\0"
$fixed = iconv('utf-16le', 'utf-8', $mangled)
# "iON kit de support V\xC3\xA9lo"
```

but it would be best to go back to the original input data and re-import it properly really.

Just removing zero bytes from a UTF-16-encoded bytes string (`str_replace("\0", '', $mangled)`) isn't really fixing it, it would work for the ASCII characters (U+0000–U+007F) but you would end up with ISO-8859-1 bytes for characters U+0080–U+00FF (more usually you would want UTF-8) and any other characters outside that range would remain unreadable nonsense.